# DB changes made in fixture don't seem to persist to test

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm writing some Pytest code using a sqlite db, to test some logic. I setup a root level fixture to instantiate a db engine:

```py
class SqliteEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        self._conn_engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
        self._conn_engine.execute("pragma foreign_keys=ON")

    def get_engine(self):
        return self._conn_engine

    def get_session(self):
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self._conn_engine, autoflush=True)
        return Session()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def sqlite_engine():
    sqlite_engine = SqliteEngine()
    return sqlite_engine
```

Then in my test class, I have

```py
class TestRbac:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def setup_rbac_tables(self, sqlite_engine):
        conn_engine = sqlite_engine.get_engine()
        conn_engine.execute("attach ':memory:' as rbac")
        Application.__table__.create(conn_engine)
        Client.__table__.create(conn_engine)
        Role.__table__.create(conn_engine)

        session = sqlite_engine.get_session()

        application = Application(id=1, name="test-application")
        session.add(application)
        session.flush()

        client = Client(id=0, name="Test", email_pattern="")
        session.add(client)
        session.flush()
```

Finally in the test in that class, I tried

```py
    def test_query_config_data_default(self, sqlite_engine, setup_rbac_tables, rbac):
        conn_engine = sqlite_engine.get_engine()
        session = sqlite_engine.get_session()

        client = Client(id=1, name=factory.Faker("name").generate(), email_pattern="")
        session.add(client)
        session.flush()

        clients = sqlite_engine.get_session().query(Client).all()
        for client in clients:
            print(client.id, client.name)
```

However, only one client prints (and if I try for `Application`, none print), and I can't figure out why. Is this a problem with the fixture scopes? Or the engine? Or how sqlite works in pytest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this but I think you need to define the fixture in such a way that the session is shared unless you plan to commit in each fixture.  In `setup_rbac_tables` the session is destroyed with the function scope.  And when get_session is called again a new session is created.

In my pytest sqlalchemy tests I do something like this, where the db fixture is a db session that is reused between fixtures and in the test:

```
@pytest.fixture
def customer_user(db):
    from ..model.user import User
    from ..model.auth import Group
    group = db.query(Group).filter(
        Group.name == 'customer').first()
    if not group:
        group = Group(name='customer', label='customer')
    user = User(email=test_email_fmt.format(uuid4().hex), group=group)
    db.add(user)
    return user
```